# Get position of a specified div then create new div and apply the positions to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a 'add' button which is a simple circle, on hover it opens up some options around it which are clickable (shown in the image added).

on hover
[image]

Normal (not hover)
[image]

When you click one of them surrounding elements it hides all the other elements other than the one you clicked, the hidden elements are made visible again when you hover off.

My issue is I want to make it so when one is clicked another 3 divs ("zone 1", "zone2" & "zone3") are dynamically created using JavaScript and positioned around the clicked element in a similar style to the image attached.

But I obviously have the issue of finding the position and then adding these 3 new divs in the correct positions depending on which element was clicked and whether it is on the left right bottom or top.

Thanks!

```
<head>
    <title>Add Button</title>
    <link href="css/materialdesignicons.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">  
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="add-button">
            <div class="sub-button tl" id="temp" onclick="addNew(this.id)"><i class="mdi mdi-temperature-celsius"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button tr" id="light"><i class="mdi mdi-weather-sunny"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button bl" id="fridge"><i class="mdi mdi-fridge"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button br" id="kettle"><i class="mdi mdi-coffee"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button tlo" id="cup"><i class="mdi mdi-cup"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button tro" id="lamp"><i class="mdi mdi-lightbulb-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button bro" id="sound"><i class="mdi mdi-microphone-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="sub-button blo" id="noise"><i class="mdi mdi-speaker"></i></div>
        </div>
</header>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>


<script>
    var type;
    var elements = ["temp", "light", "fridge", "kettle", "cup", "lamp", "sound", "noise"];

    function addNew(id){
        type = id;
        for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            if(elements[i] != type){
                document.getElementById(elements[i]).style.display = "none"; 
            }
        }
        /*var div1 = document.createElement('div'); 
        div1.className = '';
        var elementStyle = document.getElementById("id").style;
        elementStyle.position = "relative";
        elementStyle.top = elementStyle.left = "50%";*/
    }

    function initialise(){
        for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            document.getElementById(elements[i]).style.display = "block"; 
        }
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add-button').hover(
           function () {
           }, 
           function () {
               initialise();
           }
        );
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $existingDiv = $("#div1"),
    pos = $existingDiv.position(),
    $newDiv = $("<div></div>").css({
        "background-color": "red",
        "position": "absolute"
    });
$newDiv.css(pos);
$existingDiv.after($newDiv);
$existingDiv.remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/uvxc1yk5/

Using `position` element: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/uvxc1yk5/2/

Comment: Thanks :) only issue is that yes it puts it in front of the div requested but my issue is now I want them to be around the div not just on top of it, and using that approach you suggested I cannot think of a way to move them to be around that div not just over it. So now want them to be relatively around that like in that image.

Comment: `pos` object has `left` and `top` properties, you now have to use them and modify them for each object "around" the main one.

Comment: Hi, Just had one final question for you... as appose to adding values using .push() I have been tryign to do this..... dataSets["data1"][3] = '10'; so that in the 3rd position of the array for data1 I add the value 10. I get the feeling that is destroying my code as I have been getting some strange errors and no value added.

Comment: On one side, keep in mind that `[3]` is the 4th position, not the 3rd (it's 0 based). On the other side,  you can only do that if the array `["data1"]` already has defined that position. You **can't** do: `var a = []; a[3]=1;`, but you **can** do `var a = [0, 0, 0, 0]; a[3]=1;`